# How to pick only part of asser alert in selenium IDE?

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I learning to work with selenium IDE, and have a problem. I'm try to test site with form. It's just name, surname, birth date and sent button.

When I click it, I got an alert with string:

*Roznica*: XXXXXXXXXXXX, *date* 23144412323, *lata* 44.312333331

And the *date* and *lata* are count from input, it's always same for same input. But "*Roznica*" it's always different. Every time when i send a new form I will got different "Roznica".

And as I said, I'm working with selenium IDE for Chrome. When I recording test it's OK, but when I run it again test stop on Assert Alert coz it's a different "*Roznica*". Can I just check only part of assert string?

EDIT:

I tried to use glob but it's not working. Perhaps I'm doing smth wrong:

[image]

Comment: DO you want to just check part match in assert, you can do something like this Assert.assertEquals(-1, "Rhapsar".indexOf("psa"));

Comment: hmm... thank U @APaul for answer, but actually, i using only gui selenium IDE, and I don't know where change it :D
It's posible to do that by "Target", "Value" or "Description"?

Comment: in selenium ide you can do pattern matching with assert using regex, try that. some help https://www.tutorialspoint.com/selenium/selenium_ide_pattern_matching.htm

Comment: @APaul thank U, that's very useful, looks like something what I need but i have a problem to implement that glob. I tried different ways, and it's still not working. I update my post by screen

Comment: sorry. I never used the IDE, always programmed it. Cannot you give you more specific !

Comment: Thank u anyway :) it's really helpful. Maybe now I figure it out :)

Comment: I am adding my point as a answer. Add comment to that if you can figure out. Will help others